# Create a dockerfile that runs a python http server to display an html file

Tags: html, python-2.7, docker, dockerfile

I have a directory with one simple HTML file (name: index.html) which displays some basic text. I run the python command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7000
```

to run a server, at port 7000, in the same directory to display the page in a browser.

Now I want to be able to dockerize this process and need help with that.

Basically, the dockerfile should run a server at 7000 port using this python command and then display the html on a browser.

What I thought of:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
COPY index.html
FROM python:latest
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python SimpleHTTPServer 7000", "-m"]
```

Also, how would I build and run this file once it is done?

I am pretty sure this won't work but since I am new to this, I don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Also, how would I build and run this file once it is done?

You were close. Several pointers:

- If you use python3 then you have to either use http.server or install SimpleHTTPServer separately
- If you use python 2.7 then you can't use 'latest' tag in manner you are using it
- Container port and your desired target local port are not the same

Here are `Dockerfile` variations for python 3:

```
FROM python:latest
COPY index.html /
EXPOSE 7000
CMD python -m http.server 7000
```

and python 2.7:

```
FROM python:2.7
COPY index.html /
EXPOSE 7000
CMD python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7000
```

alongside with build

```
docker build -t my-docker-image .
```

and run commnand:

```
docker run --rm -it --name my-docker-instance -p 80:7000 my-docker-image
```

After run you can go to `http://localhost` to get container's port 7000 there, providing your host doen't run something on port 80 (remap if so).

Notes:

- Using latest image is ok for development, but problematic in production
- work dir is set to root, maybe you would like to position files appropriately
- running code off simple server is ok for defvelopment

Edit:
I see that b0gusb beat me to it :)

Comment: why isn't cmd block like this `[ "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7000" ]`, i tried it and got `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"python -m http.server 8888\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

Comment: @saviour123 Try changing `python` to `python3`

Comment: If you want to run all html files as a general rule and not only `index` I would put `copy . . ` This copies the files to the same destination structure as the source.